# Change navbar color dependent on which div on the page Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, navbar

I'm new to react, but I'm trying to figure out how to change the navbar color and elements as I scroll the page so I can give it the different color for each div section. the problem I'm running into is that the page content and navigation bar are on different component files. how do i access the elements and what is the best way to do it.

Highly appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why can't you get the scroll data inside the parent component for both the navigation bar and the sections so that you can pass the props to the components that need to change color?